# Obtener si una fecha cae en dia festivo Nacional de España en Kotlin para Android

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime

Estoy creando una utilidad de fechas para determinar si una fecha concreta cae en festivo nacional de España

**Festivos España 2021**

- viernes, 1 de enero de 2021 - Año Nuevo
- miércoles, 6 de enero de 2021 - Epifanía del Señor
- viernes, 2 de abril de 2021 - Viernes Santo **
- sábado, 1 de mayo de 2021 - Fiesta del Trabajo
- martes, 12 de octubre de 2021 - Fiesta Nacional de España
- lunes, 1 de noviembre de 2021 - Día de todos Los Santos
- lunes, 6 de diciembre de 2021 - Día de la Constitución Española
- miércoles, 8 de diciembre de 2021 - La Inmaculada Concepción
- sábado, 25 de diciembre de 2021 - Natividad del Señor

Las fechas si son exactas no tengo nigún problema en detectarlas, tengo ese código

```kotlin
object DateSpainUtils {

    fun isBusinessDay(date: Date? = Date()): Boolean {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        date?.let { cal.time = it }

        val dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        return !(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY)
    }

    fun isFestivitySpain(date: Date? = Date()): Boolean {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        date?.let { cal.time = it }

        // check if New Year's Day 1 January
        if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY
            && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1
        ) return true

        ....

        //Good Friday (Viernes Santo)
        ?????

        return false
    }

 
}
```

El único que no ser detectar es el Viernes Santo, que es de esas fechas que no coinciden con un dia especifico.
Alguien sabe como detectar el viernes Santo dependiendo de un año?

Comment: He encontrado eso que pueda servir, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Implementaciones_del_algoritmo_de_c%C3%A1lculo_de_la_fecha_de_Pascua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que esta festividad se base en el calendario Hebreo que está centrado en la luna para marcar el equivalente a los meses por ende tiene más meses en un año y no coinciden con los 12 del calendario Gregoriano.

Con este Código podrás calcular las fechas de cada año:

```
class Pascua {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val domingoResureccion = DomingoResurreccion(2021)
        println("Viernes Santo: " + domingoResureccion.minusDays(2))
        println("Domingo de Resureccion: $domingoResureccion")
    }

    fun DomingoResurreccion(year: Int): LocalDate {
        var day = 0
        var month = 0
        val g = year % 19
        val c = year / 100
        val h = (c - (c / 4) - ((8 * c + 13) / 25) + 19 * g + 15) % 30
        val i = h - (h / 28) * (1 - (h / 28) * (29 / (h + 1)) * ((21 - g) / 11))
        day = i - (year + (year / 4) + i + 2 - c + (c / 4)) % 7 + 28
        month = 3
        if (day > 31) {
            month++
            day -= 31
        }
        return LocalDate.of(year, month, day)
    }
}

Salida de Datos:
Viernes Santo: 2021-04-02
Domingo de Resurrección: 2021-04-04
```

> Este Código se base en el siguiente enlace escrito en C#
> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10860/Calculating-Christian-Holidays

Answer (score 0):

Buscando más por internet he econtrado la siguiente [entrada de un repositorio](https://gitlab.deondigital.com/open/csl-cordapp-examples/-/blob/v0.75.0/external-decls/cordapps/src/main/kotlin/org/foocorp/external_decls/cordapp/DanishBusinessDays.kt)

```kotlin
// This algorithm is copied from
// https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A5ske#Beregning_af_datoen_for_p%C3%A5skedag
// There's also a longer article describing it in English.
// https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/hovo/downloads/text1_08b.pdf
internal fun easterSundayForYear(year: Int): LocalDate {
    val a = year.rem(19)
    val b = year.div(100)
    val c = year.rem(100)
    val d = b.div(4)
    val e = b.rem(4)
    val f = (b + 8).div(25)
    val g = (b - f + 1).div(3)
    val h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15).rem(30)
    val i = c.div(4)
    val k = c.rem(4)
    val l = (32 + 2 * e + 2 * i - h - k).rem(7)
    val m = (a + 11 * h + 22 * l).div(451)
    val n = (h + l - 7 * m + 114).div(31)
    val p = (h + l - 7 * m + 114).rem(31) + 1
    return LocalDate.of(year, n, p)
}
```

Más o menos es lo mismo pero usando más variables para computar